# stuck with pretty url in mvc php using localhost apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost, friendly-url

my root or index project is `http://localhost/myapp`

how to convert

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.php?controller=song&id=32&action=edit
```

to

```
http://localhost/myapp/song/32/edit
```

my project in folder `c:\php\www\myapp`

Comment: Have you researched mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^myapp/index.php?controller=song&id=([0-9]+)&action=edit/$ myapp/song/$1/edit [L]
```